# php error installing imagick

Tags: linux, php, centos7, pecl

**System - CentOS 7.5.1804**

**PHP Version - 7.0.3**

So, I'm trying to install Imagick in order to be able to render/make an image off the first page of a PDF.

I'm tried to understand how it is setup, but I'm missing something, so I'll reproduce what I've and what I've got so far:

After a long list of errors, I got down to these 4 instalations:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh ImageMagick-7.0.8-9.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh ImageMagick-libs-7.0.8-9.x86_64.rpm 
sudo yum install php70-php-pecl-imagick.x86_64
sudo php go-pear.phar
```

When I'm trying to run this: `sudo /usr/bin/pecl install imagick`, it's giving me the following error:

> WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
>   downloading imagick-3.4.3.tgz ...
>   Starting to download imagick-3.4.3.tgz (245,410 bytes)
>   ............................................done: 245,410 bytes
>   19 source files, building
>   running: phpize
>   Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
>   The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
>   ERROR: `phpize' failed

So, after checking that 'php-devel' is somewhat not here, I try to install it and I get this:

> Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-devel-1.3.10-2.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                  Requires: php-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) = 1.3.10-2.el7.remi.5.6
>                  Available: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-1.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) = 1.3.10-1.el7.remi.5.6
>
> Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-2.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>
> Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
>
> Installed: php-common-7.0.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)
>                      php(zend-abi) = 20151012-64
>   Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64 (base)
>                      php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
>   Available: php-common-5.6.36-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
>   Available: php-common-5.6.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php(zend-abi) = 20131226-64
>
> Error: Package: php-devel-5.6.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>
> Requires: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.37-1.el7.remi
>
> Installed: php-cli-7.0.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)
>                      php-cli(x86-64) = 7.0.31-1.el7.remi
>   Available: php-cli-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64 (base)
>                      php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-45.el7
>   Available: php-cli-5.6.36-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.36-1.el7.remi
>   Available: php-cli-5.6.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.37-1.el7.remi
>
> Error: Package: php-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-2.el7.remi.5.6.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>
> Requires: php(api) = 20131106-64
>
> Installed: php-common-7.0.31-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)
>                      php(api) = 20151012-64
>   Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64 (base)
>                      php(api) = 20100412-64
>   Available: php-common-5.6.36-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php(api) = 20131106-64
>   Available: php-common-5.6.37-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php56)
>                      php(api) = 20131106-64

What am I doing wrong/what am I missing?

Comment: Why are you using individual RPM files? Imagick is available either in remi's repo or Epel/Base CentOS...

Comment: Because I'm new to installing php extensions and somewhat, this is what I've tried. The objective I'm trying to achieve, according to google, is to convert a pdf into an image and I got to Imagick. I've tried several tutorials and resolving conflits but with no success, thats why I end up here requesting aid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mixed a whole bunch of manually downloaded RPMs (some built for the wrong versions of PHP, Imagick or other things) and conflicting repositories. Stop now. Don't manually download RPMs.

You've done well to use Remi's PHP repositories, but you've enabled his repo for PHP 5.6, while you *say* you want PHP 7.0. You need to disable the remi-php56 repo and enable the remi-php71 or remi-php72 repo (7.0 is EOL, don't use it).

After getting the correct repo enabled, use `yum distro-sync` to replace all the wrong versions of packages with correct versions of packages. You'll also need to remove some packages you got from SCL or other repos, such as those with names starting with `php70-`.

Finally, you can get to installing the package you were looking for:

```
[root@llothien ~]# yum install php-pecl-imagick
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
epel/x86_64/metalink                                     |  14 kB     00:00     
epel                                                     | 3.2 kB     00:00     
error-rl                                                 | 3.0 kB     00:00     
mariadb                                                  | 2.9 kB     00:00     
nginx                                                    | 3.5 kB     00:00     
remi                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00     
remi-php72                                               | 2.9 kB     00:00     
remi-safe                                                | 2.9 kB     00:00     
rhel-7-server-extras-rpms                                | 3.4 kB     00:00     
rhel-7-server-optional-rpms                              | 3.5 kB     00:00     
rhel-7-server-rpms                                       | 3.5 kB     00:00     
saltstack-salt                                           | 3.0 kB     00:00     
(1/12): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                             | 933 kB   00:00     
(2/12): epel/x86_64/primary                                | 3.6 MB   00:00     
(3/12): mariadb/primary_db                                 |  61 kB   00:00     
(4/12): remi-php72/primary_db                              | 195 kB   00:00     
(5/12): rhel-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64/primary_db        | 420 kB   00:00     
(6/12): rhel-7-server-extras-rpms/x86_64/updateinfo        | 273 kB   00:00     
(7/12): remi/primary_db                                    | 2.2 MB   00:00     
(8/12): remi-safe/primary_db                               | 1.3 MB   00:01     
(9/12): rhel-7-server-optional-rpms/7Server/x86_64/primary | 7.2 MB   00:00     
(10/12): rhel-7-server-optional-rpms/7Server/x86_64/update | 2.1 MB   00:00     
(11/12): rhel-7-server-rpms/7Server/x86_64/updateinfo      | 2.9 MB   00:00     
(12/12): rhel-7-server-rpms/7Server/x86_64/primary_db      |  55 MB   00:01     
epel                                                                12647/12647
Package php-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-10.el7.remi.7.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@llothien ~]#
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and the explanation! I've now encountered another error but it's due to Imageick and trying to find the file, I think I can figure the rest out